# Error when realloc in c (exception trown (ucrtbased.dll))

Tags: c, realloc

the function get a sentnce and need to replace between the 'n' first words.
when it's come to the first realloc the program stop and the error shown up.
I try a lot of combination of sentences, the new memmory i ask for is bigger then the exists memory.

my function:

```
void Reverse(char **sentence, int n)
{
    int m;
    char *temp;
    for (m = 0; m < n; m++, n--)
    {
        temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(sentence[m]) * sizeof(char));
        temp = sentence[m];
        sentence[m] = (char*)realloc(sentence[m], strlen(sentence[n]) * sizeof(char));
        sentence[m] = sentence[n];
        sentence[n] = (char*)realloc(sentence[n], strlen(temp) * sizeof(char));
        sentence[n] = temp;
        free(temp);
        printf("%s ", sentence[m]);
    }
}
```

[**Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBkH1.png)

[image]

Comment: What error you found?

Comment: Unless you really know what you are doing, allocating just enough space with `strlen(x)` is one too short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at these two lines:

```
temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(sentence[m]) * sizeof(char));
temp = sentence[m];
```

In the first you allocate memory and make `temp` point to that memory. In the next line you *reassign* `temp` to point somewhere else.

You do this for your reallocations as well.

Also note that by doing e.g.

```
sentence[m] = sentence[n];
```

you copy a *pointer* and not the contents of the memory the pointer is pointing to. It is a *shallow* copy. If you fix this to copy the actual contents (and have a *deep* copy) then you must remember that strings in C are terminated by an extra character not counted by `strlen`. For example the string `"hello"` is actually *six* characters long with the terminator. You must allocate space for this terminator as well.

Comment: so actually i need to make it (strlen(x)+1) and use strcpy or something else?